# Virtual size in docker is always increasing with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, bluebird

I am developing a little program with nodejs and [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) which goal is to generate a certain amount of PDF files. The program is working with the [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) module in order to achieve concurrency. The problem is that the use of Physical and virtual memory does not stop to increase. The size of all the generated documents is approximately 25GB, but the used memory in the docker container is much bigger:

```
pdf-generator     64.2GB (virtual 68.4GB)
```

We generate the PDF with Puppeteer in this way:

```
async function generatePDF(browser, num) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    const pdfUrl = pdfPathURL(num);
    await page.goto(pdfUrl, {
      waitUntil: ["domcontentloaded", "networkidle0", "load"],
      timeout: 300000,
    });
    // await page.waitForLoadState({ waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
    const buffer = await page.pdf({
      format: "A4",
      printBackground: true,
      landscape: true,
      preferCSSPageSize: true,
    });
    await page.close()
    return buffer.toString("base64");
  } catch (error) {
    let messageError = error;
    console.log(messageError);
    return "";
  }
  } finally {
   await page.close();
  }
}
```

[EDIT]
This is the code that opens the Chromium instance. One per request:

```
    async function generatePDFFile(id) {
      let pdfFile;
      let errorGeneration = "";
      const browser = await launchPuppeteer();
      try {
       if (!browser) {
        errorGeneration = `Error getting Chromium instance`;
       }
        if (!browser.isConnected()) {
          errorGeneration = `Error connecting to Chromium`;
       }
      pdfFile = await generatePDFPage(browser, id);

      console.log(`PDF file generated of id:`, id);
  } catch (error) {
    errorGeneration = error;
    console.log("errorGeneration: ", error);
  }
  finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
  return { id, pdf: pdfFile, error: errorGeneration };
}
  const puppeteerParams = {
    headless: true,
    args: [
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--font-render-hinting=none",
      '--single-process', 
      '--no-zygote'
    ],
  };
```

The `top` command in the container

```
Tasks:  19 total,   1 running,  18 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 45.4 us, 11.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 42.5 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.9 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15862.5 total,   1418.4 free,   9686.2 used,   4757.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   1291.0 free,    757.0 used.   4953.4 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  34855 myuser  20   0 1124.8g 222708 149664 S  81.0   1.4   0:02.74 chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  34810 myuser  20   0 1124.8g 212544 146712 S  77.3   1.3   0:02.61 chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  34918 myuser  20   0 1124.8g 184764 141052 S  36.7   1.1   0:01.10 chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     31 myuser  20   0  706628 142100  33080 S  35.7   0.9   2:19.22 node                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  34968 myuser  20   0 1124.7g 136748 112832 S   9.3   0.8   0:00.28 chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  35062 myuser  20   0 1124.7g 138452 114036 S   9.0   0.9   0:00.27 chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  35013 myuser  20   0 1124.8g 137448 113456 S   8.3   0.8   0:00.25 chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     60 myuser  20   0  965160 103512  33040 S   7.7   0.6   0:22.25 node                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  35106 myuser  20   0 1124.6g 105352  89208 S   5.0   0.6   0:00.15 chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      8 myuser  20   0  630596  51892  32908 S   0.7   0.3   0:04.14 node                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      1 myuser  20   0    2420    524    452 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.05 sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     19 myuser  20   0  707412  57724  35064 S   0.0   0.4   0:02.26 npm start                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     30 myuser  20   0    2420    580    512 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     48 myuser  20   0  705296  53336  34512 S   0.0   0.3   0:01.71 npm run example                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     59 myuser  20   0    2420    524    456 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  24495 myuser  20   0 1124.7g 140500 116068 S   0.0   0.9   0:00.31 chrome                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  31812 myuser  20   0    4100   3376   2948 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.05 bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  31920 myuser  20   0    7012   3420   2848 R   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 top                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  34415 myuser  20   0 1124.8g 138368 114276 S   0.0   0.9   0:00.28 chrome
```

There are 8 chrome processes because I am concurrently doing 8 requests. The memory continues increasing

Comment: Are you opening and not closing a browser handle per request? Timeout: 0, especially with `networkidle0` is pretty dangerous, potentially waiting forever. I'd make that some high number to avoid false positives and actually log the problem. If something is stuck for more than, say, 5 minutes, you should probably bail. If a throw does happen, `page` is never closed. Use a `finally` block to make sure it's closed regardless of happy/sad paths. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: `let result;` is unused. Are you using eslint?

Comment: @ggorlen Ok, thank you very much for the reply. I've changed the timeout and I've added the finally blocks. The ```let result``` was a mistake. The browser is closed and opened after every request, I've added this code to the answer as well.